# Push from a clone to original in gitorious

Tags: git, gitorious

My team has switched from github to gitorious and I am struggling on the learning curve.  I cloned the core repo and created my own sandbox. I then made the core the upstream and made all of my changes in my sandbox.  I pulled everything and have it all conflict free but I can not figure out how to now push my changes back to the original core. I tried to use the merge request feature that is built into gitorious.  When I use that GUI to create a merge request the bottom part where I am supposed to select the range of commits is blank and so it throws an error when I try and submit.

Can someone explain a workflow for me how I can push the changes from my sandbox back into the core?  I tried just pushing it with something like :

`git push git@git.site.com:site-core/core.git`

It looks like everything worked, no errors, but I am not seeing it show up in gitorious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Gitorious merge request web UI you must select both a source repo+source branch and a destination repo+destination branch. For anything to show up in the commit range (which was blank in your case), there has to be commits in the source which aren't already in the destination.